# Remove the divider in particular row in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have list with some custom views in each row.

I want to remove the divider for only 10th row.

Can anyone give suggestion on this issue?

**Note**: I don't want to remove entire list.

[image]

Comment: I would remove default separators, as they are not managed by single one, and use my own custom, so controllable, and by condition added/removed when/where needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    //
//  DemeView.swift
//  TalkPeak
//
//  Created by Sercan KAYA on 30.12.2020.
//

import SwiftUI

struct DemeView: View {
    @State var listes = [DeneModel(title: "a"),DeneModel(title: "b"),DeneModel(title: "c"),DeneModel(title: "d"),DeneModel(title: "e"),DeneModel(title: "f"),DeneModel(title: "g"),DeneModel(title: "h")]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<self.listes.count, id:\.self){i in
                VStack {
                    ViewModel(deneModel: self.listes[i])
                    if self.listes.count != i + 1 {
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemeView()
    }
}


struct ViewModel : View {
    var deneModel : DeneModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.deneModel.title)
            
        }
    }
}
struct DeneModel {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
}
```